# Conditional Vue component rendering based on ASP Policy assignment

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core

I have an .NET Core backend which is served by a `Vue.js` frontend.

We have a one-to-many Customer-User relationship, and want to be able to assign one or many users to administrate other users for their customer account.

Using `Razor` views this was simple as I could simply use

`UserManager.IsInRole("Admin") { // admin panel button here }...`

And serve a clickable button, which would direct to a route authorized using

`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`.

At run-time, the Razor view simply wouldn't compile the Admin Panel button if you weren't in the correct `Role`, but I'm struggling to achieve similar/identical logic when using a `JWT Bearer Token` and `Policy`.

I can authorizes `Routes` or `Actions` using `Policy` assignment:

```
 // Startup.cs
options.AddPolicy("User", policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtConstants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, JwtConstants.JwtClaims.User));

// Controller.cs
[Authorize(Policy = "User")]
```

But I'm struggling to decide how to conditionally mount a Vue component for the Admin Panel based on the policy assigned to the user.

In the backend everything is correctly authorized, so you can't navigate or interact with admin controls without being assigned an `Admin` policy, but rendering this sensibly on the frontend is causing some trouble.

A simple solution would be to simply return an object once a successful signin is completed, such as:

```
var auth = {
    Jwt: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    Policy: 'Admin'
}
```

And then save the `Policy` prop in `LocalStorage`, then mount the admin `Component` based off that, but I'm wondering if there's a better way that won't expose the Admin controls to someone who can (trivially) edit `LocalStorage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may add user related info inside the jwt when creating the token.

Comment: The JWT contains the policy related info, which is how I can authenticate requests in the `Controllers`, but I don't want to provide a client-side decoder to parse it out of the token. That way you can fake the JWT by reversing the decoder.

Comment: No, it's secure to decode the token in the client side. Just embed jwt-decode library. https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/issues/4